# SQL Server search for "ὡ" (U+1F61) matches all?

Tags: sql, sql-server

One of our QA engineers stumbled on this one:

```
    SELECT DisplayName
    FROM Products
    WHERE (DisplayName LIKE N'%ὡ%')
```

This query matches 100% of the DisplayName values even though none of them contains "ὡ" (U+1F61). DisplayName is nvarchar(max). We'd like to prevent this from happening. Thoughts?

Comment: Whatever it is, it's fully reproducible on [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d41d8/23189): `select 1 where N'abc' like N'%ὡ%'` returns `1` for SQL Server 2012.

Comment: @hvd For the hell of it I tried your query on SQL fiddle, but with Postgres .. and it seems it did not return `1`

Comment: Seems to be a [collation issue](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d41d8/23193).

Comment: Collation would be for sorting but it shouldn't affect LIKE searches

Comment: @cpk "*[`LIKE` comparisons are affected by collation.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179859.aspx) For more information, see `COLLATE (Transact-SQL)`.*"

Comment: @cpk No, it's intentional that collation also affects searches. The easy example is that `N'A' LIKE N'%a%'` depends on whether you're dealing with a case-sensitive collation, but there are also more complicated examples, such as `N'Strasse' LIKE N'Straße'`, which depends on the collation as well, because some collations make `ss` and `ß` equal, but others don't. Regardless, in this particular case, the result seems to be rather wrong.

Comment: Thanks. I see. Puzzled why it's working like a wildcard; same as DisplayName LIKE N'%'.

Comment: Don't use `SQL` collations unless you have a very good reason to do so. There are plenty of odd issues like this. Use the most up to date collation for your version e.g. `100` collation for 2008.

Comment: @MartinSmith thank you. This gives us a good direction.

Answer (score 5):

Yep, looks like Martin Smith was correct about a `100` collation group. The example below (tried on 2014) proves that:

```
declare @t table (
    ValueSQL nvarchar(20) collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS,
    ValueWin nvarchar(20) collate Latin1_General_CI_AS,
    ValueWin100 nvarchar(20) collate Latin1_General_100_CI_AS
);

insert into @t
select 'Abc', 'Abc', 'Abc';

SELECT case when t.ValueSQL like N'ὡ%' then t.ValueSQL end as [MatchSQL],
    case when t.ValueWin like N'ὡ%' then t.ValueWin end as [MatchWin],
    case when t.ValueWin100 like N'ὡ%' then t.ValueWin100 end as [MatchWin100]
FROM @t t;
```

Comment: Thanks for confirming and the example.