# SQL Server - Problems with special character ª and º

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have problems with specials characters ª and º

I want to do something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM tabla WHERE name like '%'ª'%'
```

-or the same-

```
SELECT * FROM tabla WHERE name like '%'+char(170)+'%'
```

---

```
SELECT * FROM tabla WHERE name like '%'º'%'
```

-or the same-

```
SELECT * FROM tabla WHERE name like '%'+char(176)+'%'
```

But The results, in the first case are names with "a" and in the second case are name with "o"

Any Ideas?

Thank you very much!

Comment: This has certainly to do with the collation you're using. Check the collation in your Server/DB properties and/or use the [COLLATE() function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184391.aspx).

Comment: A similar problem to what? To http://stackoverflow.com/q/27282377/11683 ?

Comment: as @X.L.Ant said, you are probably using an accent insensitive collation. Try `SELECT * FROM table WHERE name like '%ª%' COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS`

Comment: Why are you guys commenting your answers?

Comment: @Dan - because 'you guys' do not consider their guesses or speculations or simple links as proper answers.

Comment: Thanks everybody...The solution was: SELECT * FROM table WHERE name like '%ª%' COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS

Answer (score 1):

**The following collations will read CHAR(170) as "a":**

- SQL_Croatian_CP1250_CI_AS
- SQL_Croatian_CP1250_CS_AS
- SQL_Czech_CP1250_CI_AS
- SQL_Czech_CP1250_CS_AS
- SQL_Hungarian_CP1250_CI_AS
- SQL_Hungarian_CP1250_CS_AS
- SQL_Latin1_General_CP1250_CI_AS
- SQL_Latin1_General_CP1250_CS_AS
- SQL_Polish_CP1250_CI_AS
- SQL_Polish_CP1250_CS_AS
- SQL_Romanian_CP1250_CI_AS
- SQL_Romanian_CP1250_CS_AS
- SQL_Slovak_CP1250_CI_AS
- SQL_Slovak_CP1250_CS_AS
- SQL_Slovenian_CP1250_CI_AS
- SQL_Slovenian_CP1250_CS_AS

**Use can use this code to test characters against your supported collations:**

```
DECLARE @query VARCHAR(MAX) = '';
DECLARE @charNumber VARCHAR(3) = 170; 
DECLARE @testText VARCHAR(255) = 'asd';

SELECT  @query = @query 
+ CASE WHEN @query > '' THEN 'UNION ALL ' ELSE '' END
+ 'SELECT Name = ''' + name + ''', ConvertsChar = CASE WHEN ''' + @testText + ''' COLLATE ' + name + ' LIKE ''%''+char(' + @charNumber + ')+''%'' COLLATE ' + name + ' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ' 
FROM sys.fn_helpcollations() 
WHERE name LIKE 'SQL%';

EXEC('SELECT * FROM (' + @query + ') a ORDER BY ConvertsChar DESC, Name;');
```

As suggested by @Lamak in the comments, you may collate your name column to Latin1_General_CI_AS or another collation to avoid this.